# WSO2 api manager 3.2.0 access permission problem

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I use WSO2 api manager 3.2.0 and I create a user x with role `/publisher`, when login in `carbon` by user x, I just could change passowrd.But when I copy the url of add `keystore` from admin to user url in browser, user x can also access to keystore as follows :
[image]

Could you please guide me to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Carbon UI is rendered based on the permissions which the particular user has. Raise a Git issue in the following repo: [Product-APIM](https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues) stating the observations and reproducing steps